# UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I have the following code which gave the warning

```
UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
  category=UserWarning
```

Below is the following code:-

```py
import  numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X = np.linspace(0,20,30)
Y = np.sin(X) + np.random.random(30)

poly = PolynomialFeatures()
params = {'degree': np.arange(20)}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = PolynomialFeatures(), param_grid = params, 
                    n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2, cv = 7, scoring = 'accuracy')

grid.fit(X.reshape(-1,1),Y)
print(grid.best_params_)
```

Output:-

```
Fitting 7 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 70 fits
{'degree': 0}
C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:925: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
  category=UserWarning
```

Here, I applied GridSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning to get the optimal degree of polynomial regression for my data.

I have also tried changing 'scoring', but nothing works.

If I manually set the degree, it works properly, but in hyperparameter tuning it throws this error.

Comment: Please, explains your issue and don't just paste your code.

Comment: Can you please answer this now?

Comment: PolynomialFeatures generates a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with degree less than or equal to the specified degree. For example, if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2]. It's not like a regression model that you can score for goodness of fit. It's used to create new features out of existing features.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe another model suits your needs.

Comment: DSteman, Thank you for your answer. But i figured it out. At first i created a pipeline with PolynomialFeatures() and LinearRegression() then did the hyperparameter tuning and it worked.

Comment: I was trying to find the best fit degree of PolynomialFeatures() for my model.

Comment: You can also find the answer in 'Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas', pg. no.- 373

Comment: So, if I understand well, the problem was that `PolynomialFeatures` is not a prediction algorithm but a feature engineering one. It cannot produce predictions and, therefore, meaningful test scores.